# Typesafe config with placeholder

Tags: scala, akka, typesafe-config

I tired to use placeholder as a key in typesafe config. I particularly use `akka`'s `reference.conf` to provide some default values shipped with a library. Here it is:

```
my {
    properties{
        prp = test
    }
}

another {
    property {
        ${prp} {                              #doesn't work
            #default config for prp goes here
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is the `my.properties.prp` is going to be overriden in dependent modules and set to some project-specific value.

In particularly, it would be useful to provide the ability of customization actor name and then use project-specific one in a configuration.

Is there a way to do something like that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412438/typesafe-hocon-config-variable-substitution-reference-path

Comment: In short - it's impossible.

Comment: @rumoku Thank you. That's sad...